# Supported data types and size limit for ApplicationData

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

It seems that it is not possible to store any kind of data in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData`. It also has a size limit.

- What data types are supported?
- What is the size limit?

Answer (score 1):

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData` gives you access to multiple sources of data. Files and settings stored locally, in the cloud, and a temporary folder.

Check out the API documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR241587

Here you have samples of how to store data in local sources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465118

For local/roaming storage:

- Use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.roamingStorageQuota` for the maximum size limit (in KB).
- You store files

For local/roaming settings:

- (MSDN) The name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most.
  Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting
  can be up to 64K bytes in size.
- Data types supported are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br205768

Comment: in terms of data types, note that URI is NOT supported, but the others at the link that @melroy quoted are